# Static Variables in Setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static

In `Obj-C` I have the following snippet in a setter called `setTime:(NSDate *)time`

```
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
if (!dateFormatter) {
    dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"h a";
}
self.title.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:time];
```

This prevents the `dateFormatter` to be created every time the setter is called.

In Swift my setter currently looks like this:

```
var time:NSDate {
    didSet {
        let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h a"

        self.title.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
    }
}
```

Is there an equivalent of how to create the static variable in the setter in Swift?

Comment: You can also make it a `private` global and initialize it with the result of a closure.

Comment: Doing it this way in Objective-C is not the best idea. You should use a dispatch_once() block instead if checking for it being NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a static type property to your class.  This will create the NSDateFormatter:

```
private static let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let df = NSDateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat="h a"
    return df
}()
```

and then refer to this in your setter:

```
var time:NSDate {
    didSet {
        self.text = self.dynamicType.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
    }
}
```